# Prestashop, error 500 when trying to access backoffice

Tags: server, prestashop, backoffice

Please I need some help with a Prestashop issue. I run a Prestashop 1.7 on an OVH shared hosting. Everything worked well until yesterday morning but then I couldn't access the backoffice anymore and got an error 500 instead. The frontoffice still works and I'm still receiving orders.

**Informations** :

- I didn't upgrade anything, neither the website nor any module.
- When I enable debug mode (define.inc.php), the backoffice works again but the frontoffice got an error : [front office error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLTfI.png). The error changed when I tried to regenerate the .htaccess from the backoffice.
- On backoffice I got that error in debug mode :

> *Notice à la ligne 81 du fichier  home/ateliertfy/www/app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/0a/c8/26/0ac82623c45234c79ace80cb79d62160793b16f3.file.list_content.tpl.php
>   [8] Undefined index: color".*

- I tried to clear the cache but I have no `var/cache` folder.
- I tried to delete the `app/cache/prod/smarty/cache` and `app/cache/prod/smarty/compile` folders but that didn't change anything.
- I tried to regenerate the .htaccess but it didn't change anything either.
- When I checked on my OVH account, I noticed they turned my hosting into php 7.3 (beta) version without noticing me, a few days ago. I went back to the previous version (7.0) but it didn't change anything.

Any clue ?
Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Lyah

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error it seems like template error.
You probably have some part of page that serves the products list.

In this list, you call the product color and if you have not assigned any color the site breaks.

Try to access the contact form for example (where there is no product) and let me know if you keep seeing the error.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your help. I finally understood what went wrong. It had nothing to do with the template in the end : In the morning I was trying to translate a module part from the backoffice and I unfortunately closed the window before the process was completely done, so it stopped half way and generated the error 500. We went back to the translation page in debug mode, resaved the translation and everything went fine again. Problem solved!